# JMX client reuse already open socket

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

I am implementing a JMX client to perform some tasks on a server enabled with JMX. I am multithreading the JMX client and for each request, I try to get a new connection from the JMXConnector. Even though I close the jmxconnector instance before I open a new one, it does not seem to close the socket from previous instance. 
This is how I create the JMX instance(I use RMIClientSocketFactory to get a default socket):

```
JMXServiceURL jmxUrl = new JMXServiceURL(String.format(fmtUrl, host, port));
    Map<String, Object> env = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (userName != null) {
        String[] creds = { userName, password };
        env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
    }
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.rmi.factory.socket", getRMIClientSocketFactory());
    jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxUrl, env);
```

The RMI socket factory I try to create is below:

```
    private RMIClientSocketFactory getRMIClientSocketFactory() throws IOException {
    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("ssl.enable")))
        return new SslRMIClientSocketFactory();
    else {
        return RMISocketFactory.getDefaultSocketFactory();
    }
}
```

After getting the mbeanserver connection, perorming the task and receiving notifications, I close it like below:

```
ssProxy.removeNotificationListener(runner);
jmxc.removeConnectionNotificationListener(runner);
jmxc.close();
```

However, this does not seem to remove underlying socket.

Could you please assist.

Comment: You need to return a singleton of the `SslRMIClientSocketFactory`.

Comment: I tried that, but since ssl.enable is not set, it was only returning the RMISocketFactory and not the SslRMIClientSocketFactory

Comment: If SSL isn't enabled you don't need to set it at all. So don't set it, unless SSL is enabled. Slight restructure of your code.

Comment: I have removed the SslRMIClientSocketFactory from the code, but the behavior has not changed. The sockets are still piling up.

Comment: Additionally, when I monitor the application via Java Mission Control, I see this growing: `JMX Server connection timeout 143`

Comment: Anyone who has inputs on this? How to expose the underlying socket and close it?

Comment: Only thing I could do is introduce a timeout for each successive requests, which would be eventually cleaned up after 30 seconds. Any other solution is welcome